# apache works fine,but netstat show nothing about apache's port

Tags: apache, system, netstat

i run into a problem:my apache listening on port 80 works fine,i can access it throug the browser,and i see the log in this apache print info regarding to my access.----so i can guareentee i access the right server,and the server is working for me.and telnet xxxx 80 ,it is ok.(xxxx is my server ip)
but when i use netstat -nap|grep 80,i can not see any thing.

i suspect that the 80 port is somewhat sensitive so my system may screen it from the netstat tool.so i change http.conf by set the port to 81 and start my apache, it works fine but still with the netstat being fooled to not display the info about 81 port.

any help? tks
i guess i can get the right state by restarting my machine,but i do not want to do this,i just want to know why!

Comment: Works fine here on Ubuntu 12.04. What os is this on?

Comment: Are you sure your `netstat` binary hasn't been replaced with one from a root kit? Also why is this flagged C and C++ when it's about Apache httpd?

Comment: uname -a
Linux rd_server 2.6.9-55.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 17:03:35 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: uname -a
Linux rd_server 2.6.9-55.ELsmp #1 SMP Fri Apr 20 17:03:35 EDT 2007 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: Also why is this flagged C and C++ when it's about Apache httpd? – tadman 23 hours ago------------because i am reading the sourcecode of apache2,and it is in c. sorry if some impropriate flag

Answer (score 0):

THe `nap` options don't show anything about processes listening on ports.  Use something like `netstat -lt` to show ports you are listening on.

Comment: netstat -lt  can not see 80 port too

Comment: If you use lt, it may show www instead of 80.  How about `netstat -ltn`?  Also, do you mind posting an example of what shows upon you machine?